# for loop i+1 in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to iterate through a matrix called `XY` with 50 rows and 100 columns (divided into 50 pairs of X and Y values descending alongside each other) with a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:50){
  slope=atan(((XY[i+1,2]-XY[i,2])/(XY[i+1,1]-XY[i,1]))*100)
}
```

So as you can see on top `XY[i+1,2]-XY[i,2])`, I'm trying to take `y` the `i`-th value and subtract it from the next one and iterate through the entire list for each consecutive pair of descending values and then divide that by that by the corresponding x increments to get the slope and convert that into an angle using `atan(()*100)`.

Unfortunately it keeps telling me that `XY[i+1,2]` is "out of bounds" and I'm pretty sure I have equal brackets on each side of the equation.

Comment: sorry if the syntax is messy couldn't get it to work

Comment: i+1 could become 51, btw do you have to use a for loop?

Comment: When `i` is 50, `XY[i+1,2]`  means row #51 and column #2. So it is clearly out of bounds. Use `for (i in 1:49)`.